# Npm package styles are not applying on class

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, webpack-4

I create my react npm package using webpack but when i install my npm package to my react project, package styles are not apply on classes. Why this happens

Here is the [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@afiniti/test/v/0.0.5) of npm package. You can install 0.0.5 version. In my webpack i used style-loader but it shows me document is not defined errors but if enable following line

```js
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
```

Document not defined error resolved but styles not apply on classes in react project

[Here is webpack file image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N5fiS.png)

[Here is package.json file image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AbcZl.png)

[Here is Test.jsx file image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NFCho.png)

[Here is the main.css build file image which webpacks generates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2i3mh.png)

[Here is the test.js build file image which webpacks generates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RTUDX.png)

[Here is test.scss file image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nGKPC.png)

Comment: Can you provide some sample code here for better understanding and can you add the link for what npm package you have created?

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Here is the link of npm package. https://www.npmjs.com/package/@afiniti/test/v/0.0.5. 
You can install 0.0.5 version. In my webpack i used style-loader but it shows me document is not defined errors but if enable following line

const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');

Document not defined error resolved but styles not apply on classes in react project

Comment: @VnoitKumar 

Here is the link of npm package. npmjs.com/package/@afiniti/test/v/0.0.5. You can install 0.0.5 version. In my webpack i used style-loader but it shows me document is not defined errors but if enable following line const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin'); Document not defined error resolved but styles not apply on classes in react project

Answer (score 1):

Your webpack is working fine. You just need to import your styles manually from your build. This usually has to be done for all packages which define styles.

For [ReactStrap](https://reactstrap.github.io/) you have to add this for styles

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
```

For [AntDesign](https://ant.design/docs/react/introduce#Usage) you need this

```
import 'antd/dist/antd.css';
```

Same way you need to take import your styles from your build. i.e

```
import "@afiniti/test/build/main.css";
```

And your styles would start working.

Example code

```js
import Test from "@afiniti/test";
import "@afiniti/test/build/main.css";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Test />
}
```

Here is a link to a simplified working [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/confident-einstein-0rhq2?file=/src/App.js). Good Luck!